# C++ Binary Search Function

Tags: c++, search, binary, binary-search

I am trying to create a binary search function. The array I am using to test is:
{1, 4, 5, 6, 9, 14, 21, 28, 31, 35, 42, 46, 50, 53, 57, 62, 63, 65, 74, 89}

Right now I think I have covered all the boundary issues, but searches for 1 and 42 come back as not found which I can't explain.

Note: If index = -1 that means that the searchKey has not been found in the array

1. 42 should be returned as index on the first pass.
2. 1 should be returned as index on the fourth pass.

Both return as index = -1

```
int BinSearch(int data[], int numElements, int searchKey)
{
    bool found = false;
    int index;
    int searchStart = 0; 
    int searchEnd = numElements - 1;

    while (!found)
    {
        index = (searchEnd + searchStart) / 2;
        // If searchEnd is next to searchStart then check both to see if either is
        // searchKey
        if ((searchEnd - 1) == searchStart)
        {
            found = true;
            if (searchKey == data[searchStart]) {
                index = searchStart;
            } 
            else if (searchKey == data[searchEnd]) {
                index = searchEnd;
            }
            else {
                index = -1;
            }
        } 
        // If index is less than searchStart or greater than searchEnd then searchKey
        // isn't in the array
        else if (index <= searchStart || index >= searchEnd) {
            found = true;
            index = -1;
        }
        else if (searchKey > data[index]) {
            searchStart = index + 1;
        }
        else if (searchKey < data[index]) {
            searchEnd = index - 1;
        }
        else if (searchKey == data[index]) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: I suspect using [`std::lower_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) would be considered cheating.

Comment: Ummm... 42 has the index 10. So it won't find it on first pass.

Comment: 19/2 = 9.5 which is truncated to 9 because you're stuffing it into an integer. It can't be found on first pass because it is at index 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
 if ((searchEnd - 1) == searchStart)
```

to this:

```
 if ((searchEnd - 1) <= searchStart)
```

When looking for 1, in the third pass searchEnd will be 3 and searchStart will be 0, so index will be 1. Since your value is on position 0, it will modify searchEnd to equal 0 in the first pass.

Comment: or simply to if( (searchEnd - 1) <= searchStart )

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved my problem. I was assuming that integer rounded up instead of down i.e. 4.5 would become 5 instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

1. 42 won't be found on the first pass as it is in index 10, but you have searchEnd=19 and searchStart=0, so the first index is 9.
2. I think the real problem in that you bail out if index == searchStart or index == searchEnd without checking that searchKey == data[index] first.